# c++ big enough interger for enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I have big old style `enum` not c++11 strong typed enum,
and I want iterate though its values, like this:

```
enum Enum {
  enBEGIN = 0,
  eFirst,
  eSecond,
  //many lines
  enEND
};

Enum val;
for (auto i = make_big_enough_integer<Enum>(val); i != enEND; ++i)
  ;
```

The question is how to implement `make_big_enough_integer`
in most simple way?

`make_big_enough_integer` should return `val` converted to integer type `int32_t`, `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` so it is possible to handle all values in `enum`.

Note1: convert to strong typed enum is not an option,
because of it is used in too many places of program,
and can not imagine regex that can replace all its occurences.

Note2: I can just insert before cycle, something like
this `static_cast(sizeof(Enum) <= sizeof(int), "error");`
or just use `uint64_t`, but I interesting to write auto adopting to platform code.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::underlying_type`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::underlying_type<Enum>::type` gives you the type that the compiler chose as the underlying integer type the enum is based on, so it's exactly the same size and representation as the enum.

```
using eut = std::underlying_type_t<Enum>;
for (eut i = std::numeric_limits<eut>::min(); i <= std::numeric_limits<eut>::max(); ++i)
  ...
```

N.B. this will iterate over the full range of values of the underlying integer type, which isn't necessarily the same as the range of valid values of the enumeration type. Not every value of type `eut` is a valid value of type `Enum`, e.g. given:

```
enum Enum { e0, e1, e2 };
```

The underlying type might be `int`, but the only valid values of the enumeration type are 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Yes, a looked at type_traits, but std::unerlying_type not attract my attention.